# how to get value from JSpinner as it updates?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

```
// amount JLabels
    JLabel amount0 = new JLabel("Amount");
    JSpinner amount1= new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    JSpinner amount2= new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1)); 
    JSpinner amount3 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    JSpinner amount4= new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    JSpinner amount5 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,50,1));
    
    //cost JLabels
  
    
    
    
    JLabel cost0 = new JLabel("Cost");
    
   
  int price = 2;
 
  int value = (Integer)(amount1.getValue());
  int total = price * value;
  JLabel cost1 = new JLabel();
   cost1.setText( "$" +total);
```

This code gives me the initial value of the spinner and multiplies it by price but I want it to record the updated value as it updates and multiply it with price. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just noticed you have also been given an example of a ChangeListener in your previous question. We have made efforts to help. You have not yet provided an [mre] so there is nothing more we can do.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want it to record the updated value as it updates and multiply it with price.

You need to add a `ChangeListener` to each `JSpinner`.

An event will be generated when the value is changed and you can then respond to the event.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Detecting Spinner Value Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#change) for a working example.

Note, this is the way Swing works. There are different listeners that can be added to each Swing component to listen for user interaction.

The tutorial has basic example for all Swing components.

The tutorial also has a section on [Implementing Listener For Commonly Handled Events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html) that you should read.

Comment: I tried that but I think my syntax is incorrect. Can you maybe show me an example of how I would use this on my code?

Comment: Again, the tutorial has a working example. Why would my example be any different?    The code you posted has nothing to do with writing a ChangeListener. I recommend you download the tutorial code and start with that code since it will probably be better structured than your current code. Then you make a change to show numbers instead of dates. Then you add logic to calculate a total. Make changes one at a time until your requirement is solved. If you want help then post your [mre] showing your to the working code.